# Database.Script Method Throwing - ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#

**Hello, I'm running the following code:**

```
database.UserDefinedFunctions[name, schema].Script(dropstoredProcOptions);
```

With this as dropstoreProcOptions:

```
        ScriptingOptions dropstoreProcOptions = new ScriptingOptions();

       dropstoreProcOptions.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
        dropstoreProcOptions.ScriptDrops = true;
        dropstoreProcOptions.IncludeDatabaseContext = false;
```

If you run the .Script() function without any parameters no errors are thrown, however once you pass ScriptingOpstions as a parameter the following error is thrown: **ArgumentOutOfRangeException**

Any help or suggestions on how I could better debug it would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arg haha... The project that generated the ScriptingOptions was using the version 9.0 dll and the project that was making the call to script() was uisng 10.0 dll of SqlServer.SMO